# A variable in my basic calculator app isn't working

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "Hello user, please enter your name: ";
string userName;
cin >> userName;
cout << "Hello " + userName + ", welcome to the addition calculator.\n Please keep in mind that this calculator only supports two numbers.";

cout << "Please enter a number for the process for addition: ";
double numberOne;
cin >> numberOne;
cout << "Please enter a second number for the process for addition: ";
double numberTwo;
cin >> numberTwo;
double sum;
sum = numberOne + numberTwo;
cout << userName + ", thank you for using the addition calculator, the sum of your answer is " + sum;
return 0; 
}
```

[image: This is the picture]

I have just started learning in C++ and tried to make a basic calculator app when there are errors in line 21. I'm don't understand what went wrong, may someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: `cin >> userName;` make sure to only ask for the first name otherwise if someone types a space between a first and last name you will have bad data in the double asked next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
cout << userName 
      + ", thank you for using the addition calculator, the sum of your answer is " 
      + sum;
   // ^^^^^   error, can't add double to string
```

you are trying to concatenate a `double` to a string which is not possible.

Instead you can chain the output:

```
cout << userName 
     << ", thank you for using the addition calculator, the sum of your answer is " 
     << sum;
  // ^^^^^^   chaining is fine
```

Or use `std::to_string` like this:

```
cout << userName 
      + ", thank you for using the addition calculator, the sum of your answer is " 
      + std::to_string(sum);
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   converting to a string and concatenating is fine
```

Comment: I think chaining the string and the variables together would be more efficient, also, what do you mean by I can tack on a double to the string, it's a separate variable right? Also thank you for your answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: But the types don't match, or rather, there is no `+` that can add a double and a string (at least if you want to do concatenation).